# Can visitors still send POST if they're not logged in?

Tags: php, forms, validation, security, verification

I have a code that goes the following:

```
if($_SESSION["verified"] !== true) { 
    header('location:login.php');
    exit();
}

else {
     //do code...
     if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
         //do stuff with code...
     }
}
```

Do I need to specify in the 2nd if tag that it should only run if they're logged in?

```
if($_SESSION["verified"] !== true) { 
    header('location:login.php');
    exit();
}

else {
     //do code...
     if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_SESSION["verified"] === true) {
         //do stuff with code...
     }
}
```

To prevent people from submitting a POST on a page they shouldn't actually be able to access?
Or is there some better way to do it?

Comment: After the first `if` block you should be guaranteed that `$_SESSION['verified']` is true. Adding that second clause as far as I can tell is superfluous.

Comment: So even if you use some cURL post software you wouldn't be able to send data to the page?

Comment: correct, unless someone had already logged in and include a valid session id with their curl request

Comment: thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want you could add a textbox where your not logged on customers write a primitive text or ask a question where they should write same primitive answer in textbox before they can submit the form. is that some thing you can use?

Comment: Oh this would be for an account management form, to make sure people can't sneak their way into changing user passwords and rights without having access to it.